# Berlekamp Massey

Tags: finite-fields

I have a question regarding to the Berlekamp–Massey algorithm. Can someone guide me to understand the idea/intuition of this algorithm?

According to the explanation in wikepedia(link:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Massey_algorithm), in each iteration, the algorithm is trying to calculate the discrepancy, $\delta$. If $\delta \neq 0$, the algorithm will update the error locator polynomial using an update polynomial B(x). However, at this point, I know that the resulted error locator polynomial will make the $\delta$ in current iteration become zero. But, how about all the $\delta$ in previous iterations? It is very hard to visualize that the algorithm actually makes all $\delta=0$.